# How can i mock my date so it can work on deployment server also

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using jest and react.

I have the following test:

```
import sut from '../../utils/timeFormater';

describe('timeFormater utils ', () => {
    test('hours should be 09 if the getHours method return number less then 10', () => {
        const date = new Date('Mon Feb 08 2021 09:18:11 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time');
        const result = sut(date);
        expect(result.split(':')[0]).toBe('09');
    });
});
```

after my deployment on the server - there the time is one hour earlier so
when i expect - `expect(result.split(':')[0]).toBe('09');`

it is working on my local machine

but it is not working on the deployed serrver - there the tests are failing because there

it receives 08 instead 09 for

`const date = new Date('Mon Feb 08 2021 09:18:11 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time');`

how can i solve this issue ?